# How to remove or reduce the white space in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How to remove or reduce the white space in bootstrap. as when i am adding another div below . it makes a large margin in between ...

```
<div class="edit-profile">
  <form action="#" id="sky-form3" class="sky-form">
    <header>Checkout form</header>

    <fieldset>

      <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-4 nopadding">
          <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
          </label>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-4 nopadding">
          <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name">
          </label>
        </section>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the divs that have `row` and `col` classes have a `no-padding` class whose contents are

```
.no-padding{
 padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: yes it works for me . thanks but is it possible i can use no padding on row class ?

Comment: Sure. Depends on how much spacing you need. If this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: <div class="row" style="padding:initial">  but not enough in section.